# Multiple Options to Case When

Tags: tableau-api

Is there a way to create several groups in Case When statement?

For example,

```
CASE [Sales Manager]
WHEN "Manager 1" THEN "Germany"
WHEN "Manager 1"  THEN "Russia"
WHEN "Manager 2"  THEN "Russia"
END
```

Such statement will assign Manager 1 only to Germany, while I need to have it for both countries. Any other possible ways to do that ?

Comment: Not from a single case statement. It will assign it to Germany as that is the first occurrence of Manager 1. Could you flip it around? Case [country] when "germany" then "manager 1" when "russia" then "manager 1"?

Comment: The countries don't exist in the dataset. I assign them based on managers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to define a table in your database (or Excel) that maps managers to countries. You just need two columns, one for manager and for country, and a row in the table for each association between a manager and a country.

That way you can easily represent a manager that works with many countries, or a country that has many managers (a many-to-many relationship).

You can then combine that table with your other data using joins or data blending. Realize that when you join data that has a to-many type of relationship that you can in general cause duplicate values to arise in the query results (e.g. the sales quota for a manager can be repeated multiple times, once for each country the manager visits). Unless your filters and work flow eliminate that case, you need to make sure your calculations account for duplication and avoid double counting.

Bottom line -- sometimes it is alot easier to specify information as data than as code.

Comment: that's a good solution. Though a quite complex one. I decided to just create 2 workbooks and create a dashboard. Fast and dirty ;)